# Cucumber not finding a route in test mode that I can see in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, cucumber, capybara

In development mode, I can point my browser at `http://localhost:3000/brands/` and I see a list of all brands, indicating that the route mapping, the index action in the controller and the `index.html.haml` file are all doing their job.

I have remembered to run `rake db:test:clone`.

In `/features/support/paths.rb` I have:

```
def path_to(page_name)
  case page_name
  when /the home\s?page/
  '/'
  when /the Brand\s?page/
  '/brands'
end
```

But when I run `cucumber features`, I get:

```
When I am on the Brand page # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
No route matches "/brands" (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

How would you go about finding the cause of this problem?

Thanks,

Steven.

Comment: can you do rake routes and give us the out put for the brands routes specifically, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rails URL helper:

```
   when /the Brand\s?page/
   brands_path
```